# Numbering figures like 2.1, 2.2 etc. after customization of the counter

Tags: numbering, counters, setcounter

I customized the counter only for a figure (e.g. 2.7, 2.8, **2.8.2**); when I try to restore the value 2.9 I get an error because I used the following command before the `begin{figure}` concerning the figure 2.9:

```
\setcounter{figure}{2.9}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

What is the right command to use? The arabic option is wrong because if I use arabic numbers it works.

Comment: counters are always integers a display of 2.9 is the section counter (2) followed by the figure counter (9)

Comment: but why are you setting the number by hand with `\setcounter` ?????

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle because I am not good in using LaTeX and I did many mistakes in numbering figures so now to avoid to renumber 30 figures I prefer to insert a figure with a custom number. Could you tell me how to get 2.9 please? If I wrote \setcounter{figure}{9}, the number of the figure is 10.

Comment: as you have only provided a small fragment it's hard to guess, but possibly `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}} \setcounter{figure}{8}`  will make the next figure be 2.9

Comment: latex should do all the numbering automatically so if you inserted a new figure after 2.8 everything should renumber automatically without having to "renumber 30 figures" so it would be better to fix your markup so the automatic numbering works rather than just add more weird code to work around previous issues. I can't suggest a fix as you have shown no example.

Comment: Have you given `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` a try? That'll (a) reset the `figure` counter variable to `1` each time a `\section` directive is issued and (b) display the `figure` caption "numbers" as `\thesection.\thefigure`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used your code, the number I got is 2.2.9. I cannot fix it because I wrote in the text fig. 2.1, ...., fig. 2.30 manually so I should change manually each number.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - The solution is *not* to "number" the caption numbers manually. Instead, tell LaTeX in a programmatic way how the caption numbers are supposed to be generated. And, change the hard-coded cross-references to `\ref` directives. Make LaTeX work for you, not the other way around.

Comment: That really makes no sense, why use latex and then undo one of its main features?  If you get 2.2.9 then your section is 2.2 not 2 as I guessed (you gave no clues, so I had to guess) so use `\thechapter.\arabic{figure}} ` if the *2* was a chapter count. Really you should put an example in your question.

Comment: Hi @Mico I tried and the number is 2.2.10; without any command it is always 2.8.2 for all the successive figures.

Comment: The `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` (or maybe `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}`?) instruction should be issued in the preamble. Oh, and do get rid of the `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}` directive.

Comment: Your example should be a complete small example starting `\documentclass` that produces the output shown. Somewhere in code you have not shown you have completely broken latex's numbering system and are asking people how to fix that without showing any code. It is not really possible to help without more information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works very well!!! Thank you very very much for the help! Could you give me a link about a tutorial on how to insert correctly figures please?

Comment: https://www.learnlatex.org/it/lesson-09  (I made a guess of language, other languages are available:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I use label and ref I cannot call the files of the figures fig1.1, fig1.2 etc. right? Because if I need to add a new figure between fig.1.1 and fig1.2 I need to change the name of the last figure in fig.1.3. Do you suggest to assign names without numbers?

Comment: No sorry you have this completely wrong. The whole point here is that latex does the numbering and automatically uses the correct reference. If you have a figure and reference it as `\ref{aaa}`  which produces 2.2  and then you add another figure earlier it will automatically renumber the figure and the ref as 2.3, or if you add a new section and this section becomes section 3, your figure and its ref will automatically be 3.2. You should never be numbering anything by hand or having to change numbers by hand after an edit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle perfect! Thank you a lot for the clear explanation. Have a nice day.

Comment: You are likely using hyperref and not adjusting the \theH... counters correctly. See Customize numbering figures 1, 2.1, 2.2, 3, 4 with AMS and hyperref for an example that doesn't produce a "duplicate ignored" message.